# Azure Blob Storage - Spring starter or Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob storage for one my microservices. We have a spring boot microservice which I would like to get it triggered every time a a file is uploaded to the blob. I see that apache camel also has a component which supports producer as well as consumer for azure blob storage. What is the difference between spring boot starter for azure blob and apache camel component for the same. I see that I have to write very less code with apache camel. Is there any drawback for using the same.

Answer (score 0):

The camel-azure-storage-blob-starter has a [dependency](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/blob/main/components-starter/camel-azure-storage-blob-starter/pom.xml#L37-L41) on camel-azure-storage-blob camel-component and provides spring-boot configuration classes to configure the camel component.

If your runtime is spring-boot, you should use the org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-*-starter dependencies.

There is an [examples repository](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/) for using Camel on Spring-Boot - there is no example for azure-storage-blob, but you can take a look at other components, the bootstrap should be pretty similar.